# Using extension methods in static methods on extended classes

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have an extension method as follows:

```
public static class PageExtensions
{
    public static int GetUserId(this Page targetPage)
    {
        var user = Membership.GetUser(targetPage.User.Identity.Name);
        return (int)user.ProviderUserKey;
    }   
}
```

Now in a page I need to use this method in a static WebMethod, so I have added another 'extension method' to PageExtensions:

```
public static int GetUserId()
{
    return (int)Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
}
```

and I call it as follows in my WebMethod:

```
PageExtensions.GetUserId()
```

Is this a good way of doing things?  Are there any other ways?

Comment: The only comment I have is that the second method is not an extension method, so you are using the same name for two different kinds of (albeit related) methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you haven't created another extension method - you've created a plain static method.

I would *personally* separate those out into a class other than "extensions" - it's clearly not an extension method. It's not too bad for a static class to have extension methods and non-extensions methods (like `Enumerable` does) but you shouldn't call it `Extensions` in that case.

You could change it into a genuine extension method on `HttpContext`, of course:

```
public static int GetUserId(this HttpContext context)
{
    return (int)Membership.GetUser(context.User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
}
```

Then call it as:

```
int userId = HttpContext.Current.GetUserId();
```

Comment: Yes, that's why I quoted 'extension method'.  I like both your ideas of not naming the class Extensions, and the HttpContect extension.  I'm at a loss which one to try first, hehe.